# Ionic 5 not loading my external javascript

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an external script  inside  my index.html in my ionic 5 application, but when i load the application on IOS phone it doesnt load this script into my project, but when i load on android device it works just fine.

Please i need help

i have tried to add the following into my meta tags from my research but still no luck

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!
May I ask wether the JS is dynamic, or could you possibly consider downloading it and then add it to the app? Is it an Angular app? If so, I would consider adding the path to the file in the `angular.json` under `scripts`. See https://www.websparrow.org/angular/how-to-add-javascript-file-in-angular-project

Comment: its a chat script, i have downloaded it aswell...the thing now is it works on android device..the chat is expected to load once the app loads too..but it doesnt load

Comment: It would be great if you could answer my questions. Is it Angular?

Comment: its an IONIC 5 project, yes it runs on angular too

Comment: Try adding it to you build: https://www.websparrow.org/angular/how-to-add-javascript-file-in-angular-project

Comment: build? which folder pls give me the steps

Comment: Add the JS to a folder in your project. Add the path to the file to `angular.json` under `scripts`. Then it will be added to your app, without needing to load it from a link. Just have a look at the link please.

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: You need to describe what exactly did not work, otherwise it is hard to help. Did the JS load at all? Are there error messages?

Comment: the script is loading into my ionic project...but it not coming up with no errors